What are best practices for migrating a Next.js JavaScript project to TypeScript
I have a Next.js project built with JavaScript, and I'm considering migrating it to TypeScript.
My current project setup:
Next.js (version 14)
Tailwind CSS
shadcn-ui components
JavaScript (no TypeScript configuration yet)
My specific questions are:
What is the recommended approach for gradually converting .js files to .tsx/.ts without breaking the existing functionality?
I am no big expert of TypeScript. Are there any automated tools that can help with this migration? What are the critical files that should be converted first?
I have read two Stackoverflow's posts on the topic:

Converting Next.js - Javascript code to Typescript
Converting Typescript to Javascript Best Practices

But these posts tackle narrow usecases, while I want to consult on the approach related to the Next.js project written in JavaScript.
Also I've reviewed the Next.js documentation about TypeScript but didn't find the answer.
So, I would appreciate practical advice from developers who have done similar migrations.

Install TypeScript and generate a tsconfig.json.
npm install --save-dev typescript @types/react @types/node

Generate a tsconfig.json File
npx tsc --init
npm run dev

tsconfig.json file example:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

Enable gradual migration with allowJs.
"allowJs": true

